# Grails - ShiroSecurity - manually login user

Tags: grails, shiro

I am trying to do relatively simple thing: log in user manually. I am using FacebookGraph plugin to connect to facebook. If user logs in via Facebook, i get his ID and I want to authenticate him in ShiroSecurity. Of course such trivial thing like

```
session.user = user
```

does not work.
I have found the code in the wiki, which should do the trick:

```
Object userIdentity = user.email
String realmName = "username";
PrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(userIdentity, realmName);
Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().principals(principals).buildSubject();
```

However it does not work. I still get redirected to auth/login with log.debug message that ShiroSubject is null. Maybe it be because I invoke this code in a service.
Any ideas how to make this work?

UPDATE:

```
 def authenticate(authToken) {
    log.info "Attempting to authenticate ${authToken.username} in DB realm..."+authToken.encodeAsJSON()
    def username = authToken.username

    // Null username is invalid
    if (username == null) {
        throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.")
    }

    // Get the user with the given username. If the user is not
    // found, then they don't have an account and we throw an
    // exception.
    log.debug "reached this point2"
    def user = ShiroUser.findByUsername(username)
    log.debug "reached this point"
    if (!user) {
        throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [${username}]")
    }

    log.info "Found user '${user.username}' in DB"

    // Now check the user's password against the hashed value stored
    // in the database.
    def account = new SimpleAccount(username, user.passwordHash, "ShiroDbRealm")
    if (!credentialMatcher.doCredentialsMatch(authToken, account)) {
        log.info "Invalid password (DB realm)"
        throw new IncorrectCredentialsException("Invalid password for user '${username}'")
    }

    return account
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `AuthController.groovy` -> the `signIn` action.

This is exactly the code you need to login. The Main Step is

```
SecurityUtils.subject.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username,password))
```

Hope that helps...

ok. This is only the starting point... take a look at your Realm-Code on `/Realms` . There you'll find an `authenticate(authToken)` closure. It seems that this gets called through `SecurityUtils.subject.login()` and handles the credentials check...

This should solve your problem with the hashed password....

Comment: not really. I do not know the user's password. It is hashed :)

Comment: please see my update. It seems that all SecurityUtils methods are delegated to closures in your realm. The link between the method and closure is not really evident...

Comment: i am not sure how it should solve the hashed password issue. It checks a username, if it exists then it tries to authenticate:  
def account = new SimpleAccount(username, user.passwordHash, "ShiroDbRealm"). How can I bypass passwordHash ?

Comment: I guess you try to help me with the step which is already done (login the user without password) , but of course I might be wrong and I might not be on the right path. What I guess I miss, is to bind somehow subject to something. Anyway, thanks for your effort!

Comment: hm. In my LDAPRealm, the `authenticate(authToken)` closure checks the password and if it's ok, returns the username. After that, the user is logged in. In this closure, you can bypass the password check and thus login without a password. (you'll also find the `skipAuth` functionality here). So you only need a mechanism to verify in this closure that the userID really one which you've gotten from facebook in the first step.

Comment: I have updated my question by pasting the code that I have. I do not have skipAuth method. Maybe I am looking at the wrong place?

Comment: ah. maybe the skipAuth is only in the LDAPRealm. But your code looks good. Does it get called? Have you tried to call it through `SecurityUtils.subject.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username,password))`?

Comment: wait - you return an account. In my code, just the username is returned... maybe it needs a string as return value for a successfull login...

Comment: no it is not called and I think it does not have to be. As I understand, this code is one of few steps in order to create Subject, which is actually the most important thing in Shiro and which can be interpreted as session. To avoid many that requires knowing password, I use completely different path to get my subject; I just build it for certain username. However Now I can see that authenticate operates on encryptedpassword, so I can take proper value directly from the database! I will take a look, thanks for the insight. +1

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Javadoc](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.1.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.Builder.html), Subject.Builder() does not automatically bind the subject to the current application thread. Try adding this after building your Subject instance:

```
ThreadContext.bind(subject)
```