# Login with passwordHash in Apache Shiro Grails

Tags: grails, shiro, user-management

I am using Apache Shiro plugin in grails for handling user Authentification.

I would like to add a feature to the admin part of the system, where our admin would be able to login for a particular user.

I want to avoid creating a new complex interface for admin.

How to login as a user, when I do not know his password, but only his passwordHash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it, but I am not sure about security of my solution, so I would like you to comment on it.

I created new action signIn which is in admin controller. This controller is only accessible by admin and no one else. The action looks like:

```
def signIn(String username) {

        def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, params.password as String)

        // Specific setting for administrator signIn
        //
        params.rememberMe = false
        params.targetUri = '/'
        authToken.host = 'admin'

        // If a controller redirected to this page, redirect back
        // to it. Otherwise redirect to the root URI.
        def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/index/index"

        // Handle requests saved by Shiro filters.
        SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getSavedRequest(request)
        if (savedRequest) {
            targetUri = savedRequest.requestURI - request.contextPath
            if (savedRequest.queryString) targetUri = targetUri + '?' + savedRequest.queryString
        }

        try{
            // Perform the actual login. An AuthenticationException
            // will be thrown if the username is unrecognised or the
            // password is incorrect.
            SecurityUtils.subject
            SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)

            log.info "Redirecting to ${targetUri}."
            redirect(uri: targetUri)
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex){
            // Authentication failed, so display the appropriate message
            // on the login page.
            log.info "Authentication failure for user ${params.username}."
            flash.message = message(code: "login.failed")

            // Keep the username and "remember me" setting so that the
            // user doesn't have to enter them again.
            def m = [ username: params.username ]

            // Remember the target URI too.
            if (params.targetUri) {
                m["targetUri"] = params.targetUri
            }

            // Now redirect back to the login page.
            redirect(action: "login", params: m)
        }
    }
```

And I also slightly modified my DbShiroRealm.

```
def authenticate(authToken) {


    log.info "Attempting to authenticate ${authToken.username} in DB realm..."
    def username = authToken.username

    // Null username is invalid
    if (username == null) {
        throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.")
    }

    // Get the user with the given username. If the user is not
    // found, then they don't have an account and we throw an
    // exception.
    def user = User.findByUsername(username)
    if (!user) {
        throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [${username}]")
    }

    log.info "Found user ${user.username} in DB"

    // Now check the user's password against the hashed value stored
    // in the database.
    def account = new SimpleAccount(username, user.password, "ShiroDbRealm")

    if( !(authToken.host == 'admin')) { // skips password authentication
        if (!credentialMatcher.doCredentialsMatch(authToken, account)) {
            log.info "Invalid password (DB realm)"
            throw new IncorrectCredentialsException("Invalid password for user ${username}")
        }
    } 

    return account
}
```

I used host field in UsernamePasswordToken to carry information who is logging in.

It would be more appropriate to override UsernamePasswordToken and add additional boolean field for skipping password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a horrible idea with loads of security issues. You should instead consider allowing a logged in admin to temporarily log in as a user.

These could help you with how to log in as a user programatically [Grails - ShiroSecurity - manually login user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169461/grails-shirosecurity-manually-login-user) and [Grails: ShiroSecurity - log in user without UsernamePasswordToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687022/grails-shirosecurity-log-in-user-without-usernamepasswordtoken)